# How to secure a webservice in .net?

Tags: .net, web-services, security

I have written a simple .NET webservice, which I will be hosted on a different server may be on different continent. I don't really know. Now, I only had its URL and I tried to use webrequest and webresponse method to access that web service vai HTTP POST. Now, I want to know is there any way to secure the webservice access, so that nobody can exploit it?

for example:

http://example.com/Verify/Verification.asmx/Verify?AccountNumber=3223&ProductName=876

Now, these are all the parameters required to call this webservice. As if now, anyone can exploit it. So how can I make it secure? Although, I am planning to get SSL and this whole thing is happening from server to server, not from client to server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a service key (much like Amazon WS) in the authorization header of the web request which could be encrypted with an algorithm of your choice, which is then decrypted at the service end and only continue with the execution if the key matches

See section 14.8 in the following URL

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Is there any other thing, I could do to make it more secure? If the request from the client is done in SSL mode then, this request will also be done in SSL from server to server, or do I have to turn it on specifically? Pardon me, for asking so many question.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you would need an SSL certificate for the server to server communication also. That paired with an encrypted authorization header should be all you need

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't have many options since you've used the old ASMX web service technology. The only ways to authenticate someone with ASMX web services, over the Internet, basically amount to "do it yourself".

If I had to do this, I'd use WCF and give myself some options. If I couldn't use WCF, then I'd create a custom HTTP header to pass username and password (over SSL!), and authenticate them on the server. Alternately, I'd use certificates on the client and require them to be sent to the server. IIS can even turn client certificates into Windows identities on the server.

Comment: WCF...

I think I can take a look on that. But still I need to access that via URL only, thats my limitation. Please help me, if you can. Any link would be sufficient.

thanks.

Comment: The WCF Developer Center on MSDN is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/. WCF should be used instead of ASMX for all new web service development.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you used to secure .NET web services before WCF was Microsoft's [Web Service Extensions (WSE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977317.aspx), now at version 3.0. I have used it successfully in a commercially-available product, and it is rather good as it is based on the W3C ws-* standards. It is possible to successfully interoperate with that from .NET clients (obviously) but also from Java clients if you use Apache Axis. Download at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en

Comment: I strongly recommend against even _thinking_ about WSE! WSE is quite obsolete, having been replaced by WCF. Do not use WSE unless you have no choice at all.

Comment: That's why I wrote /before/ WCF... The original question seems to refer to traditional .NET web services. Of course I'd also recommend WCF if there's a choice.

Comment: Just _please_ be careful about mentioning WSE - what if someone reading this decided to _use_ it? That's why I put it in such stark terms - "only if you have no other choice". I don't want to chance someone using it because "it uses .ASMX files" or "WCF is too advanced" or anything like that. WSE is obsolete, and should simply not be used, at least not on any project that matters.

Comment: @john, @Guido: Excuse my ignorance, but in what way does WSE fail?  Is it not secure?

Comment: @bnieland: WSE is obsolete, almost unsupported, and has been replaced by WCF. There is almost no reason to use it. I would only use it if I had to run on Windows Server 2000 and needed WS-Security. If you can't use WCF for some reason, then just use https.

Answer (score 0):

We do a fair number of Web services and to secure them we just added a username and password to our request object.  In your case you could just add 2 new parameters for a user name and password, or more simply just add one and use something like an authentication code, that you can make as complex or as simple as you want.

Some Ideas are something simple like a list of GUIDs that are acceptable pass keys to an encryption of the requesting servers IP address so that authentication code only works with that IP address verified by the web service.

Comment: Very Nice.. Thanks for suggestion.. But as other guys said, I will try using WCF also and see if it benefits me. Otherwise, I can always use your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a token and pass this tokenid as a parameter to every webmethod. You can maintain the token in hashtable and remove from the hashtable once the session is abandoned.

The token needs to be generated upon successful login. To generate a token id, I recommend using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: you said: You can also create a token and pass this tokenid as a parameter to every webmethod. if i follow your guide line to pass token 
with each request then how could i prevent reply attach. attacker also grab those token and send the request. guide me. thanks